# Any Recent Experience with Priority Processing of Australian Passport?

Tags: passport, australian-citizens

My friend had submitted filled Australian passport application for his infant daughter under priority processing.

He had submitted everything to Melbourne (Australia) GPO Australia Post and opted for collection from Passport office.

The official timeline is 2 business days. Just wondering if anyone of you has any recent experience with priority processing? Like does it take less or more 2 business days to collect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it recently took 4 days, but I got it mailed to me. I was told sending it back to the GPO may take longer.